# Доступ из класса модуля к переменным и модулям основной программы (Python)

Tags: python, классы, наследование, модульность

Как в классе подключаемого модуля получить доступ к переменной и модулям основной программы? Например, основной файл:

```
# <main.py>
PYTHON_VERSION = 3
if PYTHON_VERSION == 3:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote  # python 3
else:
    from urllib import urlencode, quote  # python 2.7
import mymodule
```

Класс в модуле *mymodule* не видит ни глобальной переменной PYTHON_VERSION:

```
# <mymodule.py>
class works:
    global PYTHON_VERSION

    def get_html(self):
        print (PYTHON_VERSION)
        # ошибка: name 'PYTHON_VERSION' is not defined
```

ни *quote* из *urllib*:

```
# <mymodule.py>
class works:
    PYTHON_VERSION = 3
    # ...

    def get_html(self):         
        if self.PYTHON_VERSION == 3:
            url = self.URLhtml + quote(self.title)  # python 3
        else:
            url = self.URLhtml + self.title.encode('utf-8')  # python 2.7
        # ошибка: name 'quote' is not defined
```

В одном файле, без выноса в модуль и классы, просто функциями, всё работало.

Comment: Ээ, global это вроде чтобы сделать локальную (по-умолчанию) переменную в функции глобальной. Если вам нужна общая переменная для нескольких модулей, то лучше вынести её в отдельный модуль. А по поводу urllib: его нужно будет импортировать в начале mymodule.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Если нужны константы общие для нескольких модулей, вынесите эти константы в отдельный модуль и импортируйте его в остальных модулях.

В вашем случае можно сделать так:

Создать фаил constans.py

```
from sys import version_info
PYTHON_VERSION = version_info.major

if PYTHON_VERSION == 3:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote  # python 3
else:
    from urllib import urlencode, quote  # python 2.7
```

Затем импортировать его в остальных файлах:

mymodule.py

```
from constans import PYTHON_VERSION, urlencode, quote

class Works:
    def get_html(self):
        print(PYTHON_VERSION)
        # напечатает "3"
```

main.py

```
from constans import PYTHON_VERSION
from mymodule import Works

print( PYTHON_VERSION ) # напечатает 3

w = Works()
w.get_html() # вызовет get_html которые напечатает 3
```